# How to set the browser intent as a fullscreen mode in android?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, browser

I have an android application which will load a website in the browser. i need that browser should be in a full screen mode while opening through the application. And i need to remove the address bar from the browser.
and this is my code

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

String url = "http://google.com";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
i.setPackage("com.android.chrome");
try {
     startActivity(i);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                i.setPackage("com.android.browser");
                startActivity(i);
    }
finish();
```

Comment: Not all browsers support full screen mode. And even those which support don't have API to open URL in full screen mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way you can achieve what you want is using a [Trusted Web Activity](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/10/using-twa)

This will let you show your Web page as if it was full part of your app.

> Trusted Web activities come from the web: they're rendered by the user's browser, in exactly the same way as a user would see it in their browser except they are run fullscreen. Web content should be accessible and useful in the browser first.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Call below method to make full screen mode it could help you:

```
SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
```

> added in API level 16

```
public static final int SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
```

Flag for `setSystemUiVisibility(int)`

Comment: Thanks for your response.